# my firebase query not return value in two state

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

i have an funtion that return user messages for any user but when i use userid for my query firebase working true and return messages but when i pass otheruserid unfonately not return user message

```
firebaseGetMessages({ commit, state },otherUserId) {
    let userId = state.userDetails.userId

    //messagesRef = firebaseDb.ref('userMessages/'  + userId  )   //ok
    messagesRef = firebaseDb.ref('userMessages/'  + otherUserId)  //not ok
    messagesRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
        let messageDetails = snapshot.val()
        let messageId = snapshot.key
        commit('addMessage', {
            messageId,
            messageDetails
        })
    }

)

},
```

i trying with single qutation ("'" + otherUserId +"'")and qutation('"' + otherUserId +'"') but not effect

this is my realtime database structure

```
 userMessages
  {
  "0FXpksPdL4OAf9KAXx9B0R6nzmh2": {
    "-N6giImvaGnHl2L33rA9": {
      "content": "test sms",
      "fromId": "Yto2rkMyXJNVkWS3xAOJgUjXFzI30",
      "isGroup": "true",
      "messageId": "-N6giImvaGnHl2L33rA9",
      "phone": "+989034015019",
      "timestamp": "1657533972119",
      "toId": "-N4zbr74Vw5WeYkbnVlb",
      "type": "1"
    },
    "-N6w7t_jTLazBcbLnIau": {
      "content": "Test message 1",
      "fromId": "Yto2rkMyXJNVkWS3xAOJgUjXFzI3",
      "messageId": "-N6w7t_jTLazBcbLnIau",
      "phone": "+989034015019",
      "timestamp": "1657792676492",
      "toId": "0FXpksPdL4OAf9KAXx9B0R6nzmh2",
      "type": "1"
    },
    "-N6w8651yjmhOKRHd5xG": {
      "content": "Test massege 2",
      "fromId": "Yto2rkMyXJNVkWS3xAOJgUjXFzI3",
      "messageId": "-N6w8651yjmhOKRHd5xG",
      "phone": "+989034015019",
      "timestamp": "1657792676592",
      "toId": "0FXpksPdL4OAf9KAXx9B0R6nzmh2",
      "type": "1"
    }
  },
  "diZUE8slUzbGvCXcmAMRdImyC7S2": {
    "-N6ggkKWpAW9tQSzCKvF": {
      "content": "test message group",
      "fromId": "Yto2rkMyXJNVkWS3xAOJgUjXFzI3",
      "messageId": "-N6ggkKWpAW9tQSzCKvF",
      "phone": "+989034015019",
      "timestamp": "1657533564699",
      "toId": "diZUE8slUzbGvCXcmAMRdImyC7S2",
      "type": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

i test this code but not worked:

```
    let Other=otherUserId
        messagesRef = firebaseDb.ref('userMessages/0FXpksPdL4OAf9KAXx9B0R6nzmh2' )
or 
    messagesRef = firebaseDb.ref('userMessages/'+ Other)
```

note that the userid store in vuex object with  qutation like this "0FXpksPdL4OAf9KAXx9B0R6nzmh2"  but otherUserId passed with this.$route

i not undestanding why userid returned data but otheruserid not returned data

Comment: It looks like there is a difference in the value of `otherUserId` and `userId`, so you'll want to log those and possibly compare then in your code. Without seeing how both are initialize, it is hard to say more though.

Comment: ofcourse, but i use console.log(otherUserId ,userId) and nothing difference. i think that the best practice is monitor log in firebase but not possible .

Answer (score -1):

I check traffic between web and firebase in websocket section and realize that firebase return permission denied for read other user messages
this is in inspect section - network and WS :

```
req1-{"t":"d","d":{"r":5,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/userMessages/340SgcUw8xaD2jjNlkpSlRVaqzc2","h":""}}}
    response-1-1-{"t":"d","d":{"r":5,"b":{"s":"permission_denied","d":"Permission denied"}}}
```